# RocketChat database connection based on sub-domain

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, rocket.chat

We have hosted RocketChat on AWS and I have two questions and not sure if possible. Couldn't find anything on the docs.

- Separate database and application servers from each other
- Connect to a specific database based on the subdomain in URL

Any thoughts?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely run your Mongodb servers seperately from your Rocket.Chat servers.

To route based on domain.  You would just simply have to have a Rocket.Chat instance running for each subdomain you wish to have Rocket.Chat running on.

Then when starting the instances for those domains include environment variables like:

```
# subdomain1
PORT=3001
MONGO_URL=mongodb://ip-to-mongo-host:27017/subdomain1?replSet=rs0
MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://ip-to-mongo-host:27017/local?replSet=rs0

# subdomain2
PORT=3002
MONGO_URL=mongodb://ip-to-mongo-host:27017/subdomain2?replSet=rs0
MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://ip-to-mongo-host:27017/local?replSet=rs0
```

Above of course is assuming you are running your mongodb in replicaset mode. Which for Rocket.Chat I would definitely recommend.  Especially when you go to scale the instances out to handle additional load.

Then in your reverse proxy just simply route:

- subdomain1 -> 127.0.0.1:3001
- subdomain2 -> 127.0.0.1:3002